# Device support for Core NFC? does it work on iPad?

Tags: nfc, ios11, core-nfc

Does Core NFC works on iPad?

To sum up, [iPad does have NFC chips](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/10/24/new-ipad-air-2-ipad-mini-3-incorporate-nfc-chip-for-apple-pay-in-apps-but-not-in-store-tap-to-pay-transactions), but the [Core NFC documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) does not say it support it.

> **Note**
>
> Reading NFC NDEF tags is supported on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus.

running this [iOS11-NFC-Example](https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example) on emulator will always get `Feature not supported` on all devices.

Comment: Check this for iOS 12, because iOS 12 is not allowing to import CoreNFC framework if the device is not supported, so that you even can't check reading availability. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566753/5830550

Answer (score 3):

No ! for now Core NFC don't support iPads and iPhone lesser than iPhone 7.

iPhone Series of 7, 8 and iPhone X only supported by Core NFC.
and 
if you want to identify in your code that the device your app is running on supports Core NFC or not can be done by this

```
if (NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable)

   {
        NSLog(@"NFC is Available");
}
else
{
 NSLog(@"NFC is not Available");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As in **[WWDC 2017](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/718jes6q3aac0f1a/718/718_introducing_core_nfc.pdf)**

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc)

NFC tag reading is available for iPhone 7 & iPhone 7 plus.
May be in future release they make them available.